# How to get the highest of the elements in each of multiple wrappers with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, offsetheight

I already have half of the solution, but my function only marks a single element in the entire DOM, regardless of the fact that there are several wrapper elements, whose child elements should be queried for height and the highest one of each wrapper marked. I do not need the value.

```js
"use strict";

const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slider_inner > .block");

let maxHeight = 0;
let maxHeightElement = null;
slides.forEach(el => {
  let elementHeight = el.offsetHeight;
  if (elementHeight > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = elementHeight;
    maxHeightElement = el;
  }
});

if (maxHeightElement !== null) {
  maxHeightElement.classList.add("highest");
  maxHeightElement.parentNode.classList.add("highest_defined");
}
```

```css
.highest{
  background-color: red;
}

.slider_inner{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_inner">
  <div class="block">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 3<br>Slide 3</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 5</div>
</div>


<div class="slider_inner">
  <div class="block">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 2<br>Slide 2</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 4<br>Slide 4<br>Slide 4</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 5</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your class assignment into the loop.

Alternatively you can use Math.max when you run over the wrappers

This is not marking blocks with same height, you can loop over the heights if you want to mark more than one.

```js
const sliders = document.querySelectorAll(".slider_inner");
sliders.forEach(slider => {
  const blocks = slider.querySelectorAll(".block");
  const heights = [...blocks].map(block => block.offsetHeight);
  // Find the maximum height
  const maxHeight = Math.max(...heights);

  // Find the index of the block with the maximum height
  const tallestBlockIndex = heights.indexOf(maxHeight);

  if (blocks[tallestBlockIndex]) {
    blocks[tallestBlockIndex].classList.add("highest");
    slider.classList.add("highest_defined");
  }
});
```

```css
.highest {
  background-color: red;
}

.slider_inner {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.highest_defined {
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_inner">
  <div class="block">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 3<br>Slide 3</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 5</div>
</div>


<div class="slider_inner">
  <div class="block">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 2<br>Slide 2</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 4<br>Slide 4<br>Slide 4</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that `slider.querySelectorAll(".block")` will match any element that has `class="block"` inside `slider`. Not just the direct children. If this is a hard requirement, consider changing the query selector to `":scope > .block"` instead. This will only match the direct children with `class="block"`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of looping through all the `.slide_inner > .block` elements. You want to do two loops. One through all `.slide_inner` elements. Then for each `.slide_inner` element, you want to loop through the `:scope > .block` elements to determine which is the highest within this `.slider_inner`.

```js
"use strict";

const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".slider_inner");
// loop through the .slider_inner containers
for (const container of containers) {
  // for each container, collect the .block elements that are a direct child
  const slides = container.querySelectorAll(":scope > .block");
  // exit the current iteration early if there are no .block children
  if (!slides.length) continue;
  // find the highest slide
  const highestSlide = maxBy(slides, slide => slide.offsetHeight);
  // add the "highest" class to the highest slide
  highestSlide.classList.add("highest");
}

// Abstracted away getting the item with the highest value from an iterable
// collection.
function maxBy(iterable, valueFn) {
  return Array.from(iterable, (item) => ({ item, value: valueFn(item) }))
    .reduce((max, current) => current.value > max.value ? current : max)
    .item;
}
```

```css
.highest{
  background-color: red;
}

.slider_inner{
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider_inner">
  <div class="block">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 2</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 3<br>Slide 3</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 4</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 5</div>
</div>


<div class="slider_inner">
  <div class="block">Slide 1</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 2<br>Slide 2</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 3</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 4<br>Slide 4<br>Slide 4</div>
  <div class="block">Slide 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need for prototype.call. This is more modern: `const maxBy = (arrayLike, valueFn) => Array.from(arrayLike).reduce((max, current) => (
    valueFn(current) > valueFn(max) ? current : max
));`

Comment: Other alternative to get an array from a nodelist is `[...nodeList]`

Comment: @mplungjan I do agree that both `Array.from(arrayLike)` and `[...arrayLike]` look cleaner. The difference is that both convert the array-like to an array first before calling `reduce()`, so both iterate twice through the collection whereas `Array.prototype.reduce.call` solution iterates once. Not that it has any impact with the few amount of elements in the example.

Comment: I've updated the solution to use your suggestion, but made the `valueFn()` call inside `Array.from()` (during the array conversion). To halve the amount of times the function has to be called.